# WinRT XAML - how do I style a selected item in a list view?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime

In my WinRT app I want to display a list of status values and highlight the current status. When the list is displayed it should be readonly, so no interaction with the user. Although I am using a ListView, I want any selection functionality to be disabled. I think that disabling the ListView will do the trick for that.
But for now in my code behind I have;

```
  public IList<JobStatusItem> StatusList
    {
        get
        {
            var values = Enum.GetValues(typeof(JobStatus));
            var selected = Status.ToString();
            var i = 0;
            var list = new List<JobStatusItem>();
            foreach (var value in values)
            {
                i++;
                var item = GetStatusDisplay(value.ToString());
                list.Add(new JobStatusItem
                {
                    Id = i,
                    Status = item,
                    Selected = value.ToString().Equals(selected)
                });                    
            }

            return list;
        }
    }
```

And for my XAML I have

```
                <ListView x:Name="ListStatus" 
                          IsItemClickEnabled="False" 
                          IsSwipeEnabled="False"
                          SelectionMode="Single" 
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AssignedJobs.SelectedDay.SelectedJob.StatusList, Mode=OneWay}"
                          >
                    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Path=Selected, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                        </Style>
                    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Status}"></TextBlock>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
```

And when I run this the selected status is not styled as selected. Why is this and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The binding expression (`<Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Path=Selected, Mode=OneWay}"/>`) in your code won't work as the context is not at the item level.

Due to lack of ancestor binding in WinRT, it's difficult to use pure binding to achieve what you want; however, it's quite simple to *check* the `IsSelected` property in code behind. At the end of the day, if you want a pure XAML solution, you can always wrap the code below inside a `Behavior`.

You basically want to subscribe to the [`ContainerContentChanging`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ListViewBase#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_ListViewBase_ContainerContentChanging) event of your `ListView` and manually set the `IsSelected` property of the `ItemContainer` to match the `Selected` property of your model `JobStatusItem`. Something like this -

```
    private void OnListViewContainerContentChanging(ListViewBase sender, ContainerContentChangingEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.ItemContainer != null && !args.InRecycleQueue && args.Phase == 0)
        {
            args.ItemContainer.IsSelected = ((JobStatusItem)args.Item).Selected;
```

### Another possible solution

Since you want a read-only list with a highlighted selection, it might be a good idea to completely disable any clicking/tapping interaction on the `ListView` by setting its `SelectionMode` to `None`.

And then inside your `DataTemplate`, wrap the `TextBlock` with a `Border` and give the `Border` a different `Background` whenever the `Selected` property is `true`.

Comment: I chose the "Another possible" solution and it worked. Thank you for that.

Answer (score 1):

So, I gather you want you want to **disable manual Selection** for Items in the ListView while **maintaining programmatic selection**.

The easiest way to achieve what you are trying to do is to define your ListView as `SelectionMode="Single"` and bind the SelectedItem Property to a corresponding Property of your ViewModel. To block any manual interaction, just put a Grid over it with `IsHittestVisible="True"` to block any manual interaction. Like the following:

```xml
<Grid>
    <ListView x:Name="ListStatus"
              SelectionMode="Single"
              ItemsSource="{Binding StatusList}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" 
              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource UnselectedListDataTemplate}"/>
    <Grid IsHitTestVisible="True" Background="Transparent" />
</Grid>
```

I would choose a **different approach entirely** however.

The more convenient approach to what you are trying to achieve would be to set `ListView.SelectionMode="None"` and utilize a `ItemTemplateSelector` or a `ItemContainerStyleSelector` to switch the template/style between a highlighted version and a normal version.

```cs
public class JobStatusItemTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate SelectedTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate UnselectedTemplate { get; set; }
    protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        var element = item as JobStatusItem;
        if (element == null) return UnselectedTemplate;
        return element.Selected ? SelectedTemplate : UnselectedTemplate;
    }
}
```

With your ListView defined as:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate 
        x:DataType="local:JobStatusItem"
        x:Key="SelectedListDataTemplate">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Status}" FontWeight="ExtraBold" Foreground="DarkOrchid"/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate 
        x:DataType="local:JobStatusItem"
        x:Key="UnselectedListDataTemplate">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Status}" />
    </DataTemplate>
    <local:JobStatusItemTemplateSelector x:Key="ListTemplateSelector" 
                                         SelectedTemplate="{StaticResource SelectedListDataTemplate}" 
                                         UnselectedTemplate="{StaticResource UnselectedListDataTemplate}"/>
</Page.Resources>

<ListView x:Name="ListStatus"
          SelectionMode="None"
          ItemsSource="{Binding StatusList}"
          ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource ListTemplateSelector}">
</ListView>
```

This will allow you to easily distinguish between Status Steps that happened, are in progress and will happen in the future and even allow you to easily integrate things like steps with error that occured in the time past.
Depending on wether you are using a `TemplateSelector` or `StyleSelector` you may even be able to implement symbols, images, etc. through different templates.